# Stirling's Formula Rudin 8.22

Tags: real-analysis

In the book, Rudin uses this proof

Put $t=x(1+u)$ in Gamma Function, which is

$\Gamma(x+1)=x^{x+1}$$e^{-x}$$\int $[$(1+u)$$e^{-u}]^{x}du$

Then he defines a function $h(u)$ s.t $h(0)=1$ and $$(1+u)e^{u}=exp[-\frac{u^2}{2}h(u)]$$

Later, he substitutes $u=s \sqrt{2/x}$ into the Gamma function and get

$\Gamma(x+1)=x^{x}$$e^{-x}$$\sqrt{2x}$$\int \psi du$

where $\psi =exp[-s^{2}h(s \sqrt{2/x})]$  if $-\sqrt{x/2}<s<\infty$ and $\psi =0$ otherwise

I want to know if there's something wrong with this because in the original equation we should raise $[(1+u)e^{-u}]$ to the power $x$, moreover, after calculation I think there should be $e^{1-x}$. Could someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Putting $t=x(1+u)$, and then $dt = x\ du$, in the expression
$$\Gamma(x+1) = \int_0^\infty t^x e^{-t}dt$$
gives us
$$\begin{align} \Gamma(x+1)
&= \int_0^\infty [x(1+u)]^x e^{-x(1+u)} (x\ du) \\
&= \int_0^\infty \color{red}{x^x}(1+u)^x \color{blue}{e^{-x(1+u)}} (\color{red}{x}\ du)\\
&= \color{red}{x^{x+1}} \color{blue}{e^{-x}}\int_0^\infty (1+u)^x\color{blue}{e^{-xu}} du \\
&= x^{x+1} e^{-x}\int_0^\infty [(1+u) e^{-u}]^x du
\end{align}$$

Comment: I think this part is correct, I am confused about the following part which put $u=s \sqrt{2/x}$, I think for $ \psi$ in the integral, it should be raised to the power $x$, but if that's the case, we cannot prove anything